# XSL. Passing param in string

Tags: java, xslt

Here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="RSA-InsurerID"/>
<xsl:param name="RSA-schema-version"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <rsa:DriverStatusRequest xmlns:rsa="com/rsa/eosago/schema-"
                             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InsurerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$RSA-InsurerID"
                          xmlns:ns2="com/rsa/eosago/schema-"/>
        </InsurerID>
        <IDCheckDriver>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns2:DriverResponse/IDCheckDriver"
                          xmlns:ns2="com/rsa/eosago/schema-"/>
        </IDCheckDriver>
    </rsa:DriverStatusRequest>
</xsl:template>
```

These two params values are passed via Apache Camel.

The question is how to pass and concat the param
`<xsl:param name="RSA-schema-version"/>` 
with `xmlns:rsa="com/rsa/eosago/schema-"` ?

I got my `<xsl:param name="RSA-InsurerID"/>` with `<xsl:value-of select="$RSA-InsurerID"`, but i have no idea how to pass it to the value text.

I expect this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rsa:DriverStatusRequest xmlns:rsa="com/rsa/eosago/schema-1.2" 
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<InsurerID>18800000</InsurerID>
<IDCheckDriver/>
</rsa:DriverStatusRequest>
```

Big thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you actually expect for a specific set of parameters? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems what you try to do is to generate a namespaces dynamically at run time.
For example have a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19825124/2115381) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796315/2115381) answers.
And try:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="rsa:DriverStatusRequest" namespace="com/rsa/eosago/schema-{$RSA-schema-version}" >
        <InsurerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$RSA-InsurerID" />
        </InsurerID>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Which will generate:

```
<rsa:DriverStatusRequest xmlns:rsa="com/rsa/eosago/schema-1.2">
    <InsurerID>18800000</InsurerID>
</rsa:DriverStatusRequest>
```

But I assume there will be loot more problems coming up.

Comment: Using `<xsl:element/>`  solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<InsurerID>
            <xsl:value-of select="$RSA-InsurerID"
                          xmlns:ns2="com/rsa/eosago/schema-{$RSA-schema-version}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt work for me. The text reveals as it is.

Comment: If you explicit set a value for parameter, like: <xsl:param name="RSA-schema-version">123<xsl:param> Does it work then?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt((